# Calculate expectation of Cumulative distribution function of a normal distribution

Tags: random-variables

I have to calculate the expectation of the Cumulative Distribution Function of a normally distributed random variable **X**, which has variance **1** and mean **0**. I calculated the integral of the CDF (taken as an RV distributed on [0,1] and **X** and got **0** as the answer. I am not sure if I've done this right. Is there a better way of solving this question?

Answer (score 1):

The expectation of the cumulative distribution function is independent of the distribution. The cumulative distribution function is uniformly distributed over $[0,1]$, so its expectation is $\frac12$.

Comment: For a continuously distributed variable this works. Not otherwise: for example a constant r.v. will give $1$ instead of $1/2$.